# LaTeX packages to place all images used in presentation at end of slides

Tags: graphics, packages, links

Are there any packages in LaTeX which places all the images used in a presentation at the end of the slide with link to these pictures from the slide they are used. In other words, I would like to have full-scale or zoomed image slides of the images that are used in a presentation with links to these image slides from the slides where the images are used.

As an example, imagine there are images A and B on slide 1 and images C and D on slide 2. I would like to have slides 3, 4, 5 and 6 full-scale images of A, B, C and D, with link of image A from slide 1 to slide 3, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any package doing what you want. But macros can be written for this.

The following solution provides a macros `\includegraphicstwic` to insert a picture where it is called and store some information about it to insert it again later. With its last argument, a  title for the frame with the big picture can  be given (it's mandatory). To insert the pictures again, the macro `\outputpictures` must be called after the last frame. This macro also prevents miniframes to be generated for the picture frames.

Internally `beamer`s zoom feature is used to scale the pictures to the maximum possible size. The pictures appear in the upper left corner of the text area in the frame and are zoomed to fit the height or width, i.e. pictures not wide enough will have white space on the right and those not high enough will have white space at the bottom.

Links are also set. Clicking on a picture in the presentation will lead to the frame with the enlarged one and clicking on the latter will lead back (using the PDF viewers go back function).

You can disable the title for the frames with the enlarged pictures by commenting out the line `\frametitle{#3}` in the code. And if you want miniframes for these frames, comment out the line `\nomoreminiframes`.

**Edit:**

I changed the code. It now contains the versions 1, 2a and 2b. The last two are commented out in the code. Comments show, what to enable for which version.

**Version 1** is the same as before, I just cleaned up the code a little. Please note, that `beamer`s zoom features produces the GoBack link automatically, so this can't be changed.

**Version 2a** doesn't use the zoom feature. Instead the picture is scaled to `\textheight` or `\textwidth` to be as big as possible. Unfortunately it will be smaller then with the zoom feature, but it's nicely centered.

Here the whole picture is a fixed link to it's first appearance in the normal frames, e.g. the picture in page 5 will link to page 1, even if you went there by clicking that image on page 2.

**Version 2b** is nearly the same as version 2a, but here the big picture is two links. On the left side it will go to the first appearance (like 2a), but on the right it is a GoBack link.

The new code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\makeatletter
% both version
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% necessary to get rid of miniframes for appended big pictures
\newcommand{\disableslideentry}{\def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}}
\newcommand{\nomoreminiframes}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\disableslideentry}}}
% counter for automatially generated links
\newcounter{picnum}
\setcounter{picnum}{0}
% list with infos about pictures to be appended
\newcommand{\@pltlist}{}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% version 1 start: using beamers \framezoom
% -> paper size images, go-back links
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% overlay-aware command for including pictures on the slide and on a frame at the end
% #1: options for \includegraphics, not used in frame with full picture
% #2: file for picture
% #3: title for frame with full picture
\newcommand<>{\includegraphicstwice}[3][]{%
    \@includegraphicstwice[#1]{#2}{#3}#4
}
\def\@includegraphicstwice[#1]#2#3<#4-#5>{%
    \only<#4>{%
        \stepcounter{picnum}%
        \xdef\@pltlist{\@pltlist,#2/#3}%
    }%
    \hyperlink<#4-#5>{fullpic\thepicnum}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

% get image size
\newbox\@imagebox
\newdimen\@imageheight
\newdimen\@imagewidth
\newcommand{\get@imagesize}[1]{%
    \sbox{\@imagebox}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}}%
    \@imageheight\ht\@imagebox
    \@imagewidth\wd\@imagebox
    \typeout{text: \the\textwidth\space x \the\textheight}%
    \typeout{image: \the\@imagewidth\space x \the\@imageheight}%
}

% command to insert frames with full pictures, to be called at the end
\newcommand{\outputpictures}{%
    % comment out the next line to get miniframes for the frames with pictures
    \nomoreminiframes
    \setcounter{picnum}{0}%
    \expandafter\@outputpictures\@pltlist,\@@nil
}
\def\@outputpictures,#1\@@nil{\@@outputpictures#1\@@nil}
\def\@@outputpictures#1,#2\@@nil{%
    \@@@outputpictures#1\@@nil
    \def\@tempa{#2}\ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
        \@@outputpictures#2\@@nil
    \fi
}
\def\@@@outputpictures#1/#2\@@nil{%
    \stepcounter{picnum}%
    \get@imagesize{#1}%
    \begin{frame}<2>[plain]
    % comment out next line to get rid of frame title for picture frames
    \frametitle{#2}%
    \framezoom<1><2>(0pt,0pt)(\@imagewidth,\@imageheight)%
    \hypertarget<2>{fullpic\thepicnum}{\usebox\@imagebox}%
    \end{frame}
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% version 1 end

% version 2 start: without \framezoom
% -> text size images, links to first appearance of picture
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% overlay-aware command for including pictures on the slide and on a frame at the end
%% #1: options for \includegraphics, not used in frame with full picture
%% #2: file for picture
%% #3: title for frame with full picture
%\newcommand<>{\includegraphicstwice}[3][]{%
%    \@includegraphicstwice[#1]{#2}{#3}#4
%}
%\def\@includegraphicstwice[#1]#2#3<#4-#5>{%
%    \only<#4>{%
%        \stepcounter{picnum}%
%        \xdef\@pltlist{\@pltlist,#2/smallpic\thepicnum/#3}%
%    }%
%%    \hyperlink<#4-#5>{fullpic\thepicnum}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
%    \hyperlink<#4-#5>{fullpic\thepicnum}{%
%        \alt<#4>{\hypertarget{smallpic\thepicnum}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
%}
%
%% version 2b only: needed for split link version
%%-----------------------------------
%%% get image size
%%\newbox\@imagebox
%%\newdimen\@imageheight
%%\newdimen\@imagewidth
%%\newcommand{\get@imagesize}[1]{%
%%    \sbox{\@imagebox}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}}%
%%    \@imageheight\ht\@imagebox
%%    \@imagewidth\wd\@imagebox
%%    \typeout{text: \the\textwidth\space x \the\textheight}%
%%    \typeout{image: \the\@imagewidth\space x \the\@imageheight}%
%%}
%%-----------------------------------
%
%% command to insert frames with full pictures, to be called at the end
%\newcommand{\outputpictures}{%
%    % comment out the next line to get miniframes for the frames with pictures
%    \nomoreminiframes
%    \setcounter{picnum}{0}%
%    \expandafter\@outputpictures\@pltlist,\@@nil
%}
%\def\@outputpictures,#1\@@nil{\@@outputpictures#1\@@nil}
%\def\@@outputpictures#1,#2\@@nil{%
%    \@@@outputpictures#1\@@nil
%    \def\@tempa{#2}\ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
%        \@@outputpictures#2\@@nil
%    \fi
%}
%\def\@@@outputpictures#1/#2/#3\@@nil{%
%    \stepcounter{picnum}%
%    \begin{frame}[plain]
%    % comment out next line to get rid of frame title for picture frames
%    \frametitle{#3}%
%    % version 2a: link to first appearance
%    %-----------------------------------
%    \centering
%    \hyperlink{#2}{\hypertarget{fullpic\thepicnum}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}}}
%    %-----------------------------------
%    % version 2b: left half: link to first appearance, right half: go-back link
%    %-----------------------------------
%%    \get@imagesize{#1}%
%%    \centering
%%    \vbox to 0pt{\hbox to \textwidth{\hfil
%%        \hypertarget{fullpic\thepicnum}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}}\hfil}\vss}%
%%    \hyperlink{#2}{\vbox to \@imageheight{\hbox to 0.5\@imagewidth{\hfill}\vfil}}%
%%    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\vbox to \@imageheight{\hbox to 0.5\@imagewidth{\hfil}\vfil}}%
%    %-----------------------------------
%    \end{frame}
%}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% version 2 end

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}{First frame}
\includegraphicstwice<1->[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}{First picture}\hfill
\includegraphicstwice<2->[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}{Second picture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}
\includegraphicstwice<1->[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}{Third picture}\hfill
\includegraphicstwice<2->[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}{Fourth picture}
\end{frame}

\outputpictures
\end{document}
```

The new result:

The main frames:

[image]

Frames with big pictures, version 1:

[image]

Frames with big pictures, versions 2a and 2b:

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted. I will be accepting the answer soon with some tests. Before that, is it possible to link back the original slide from the zoomed image.

Comment: @nxkryptor I edited my answer. Now you can choose one of 2.5 versions.